# How can I do a faster integration?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, warning-messages, special-functions

I have this part of my code, which takes forever to run. Does anybody know how to make it faster?

Using NIntegrate I face error:
"NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 7.38363*10^-15-7.76592*10^-15 I and 5.976982225106196`*^-10 for the integral and error estimates."

```
ℓ0 = 3;
dvec = {Sin[2 Pi/2 Sin[θ]] Cos[ϕ - Pi/2], 
        Sin[2 Pi/2 Sin[θ]] Sin[ϕ - Pi/2], 
        Cos[2 Pi/2 Sin[θ]]}

σvec = {PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[3]}

bhat = 1000 Abs[dvec].σvec

F = Table[
      Integrate[
        1.*Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ0, i, θ, ϕ]] bhat SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ0, j, θ, ϕ], 
        {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}
      ],
      {i, -ℓ0, ℓ0}, {j, -ℓ0, ℓ0}
    ];
```

Comment: Try `NIntegrate` .

Comment: There are two problems here: (i) spherical harmonics oscillate quite a lot and (ii) they are extraordinary slow in Mathematica...

Comment: even when I try NIntegrate it give me thie error: NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

Comment: Sorry I tried only cases `i==j` which are evaluated in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: If I compare `Length[Union[Flatten[Simplify[Table[withoutintegrating],0<=ϕ<=2 π&&0<=θ<=π]]]]` with `Length[Flatten[Simplify[Table[withoutintegrating],0<=ϕ<=2 π&&0<=θ<=π]]]` I see 30% of your integrands are duplicates. Might be even more if I removed constant multiples. Perhaps you might be able to take advantage of this to speed your problem up

Comment: You can replace `Conjugate[SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ0, i, θ, ϕ]]` with `SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ0, i, θ, -ϕ]`.