# How do I make this summation work faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

Is there any way to make this summation be faster?

I previously had spherical harmonics integration which was taking forever to run
[How can I do a faster integration?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190550/how-can-i-do-a-faster-integration)

Using math, I tried to use summation instead of integration, in the hope to make my program faster. But still it takes very long to calculate. Is there any comment if this is even worth trying or not

```
 dvec = {Sin[2 Pi/2 Sin[θ]] Cos[ϕ - Pi/2], 
    Sin[2 Pi/2 Sin[θ]] Sin[ϕ - Pi/2], Cos[2 Pi/2 Sin[θ]]}
 σvec = {PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[3]};
 bhat =  Abs[dvec].σvec;

a[L_, M_] := Integrate[
bhat SphericalHarmonicY[L, M, θ, ϕ] Sin[θ], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}]

Field = 
Sum[a[ℓ0, M] (-1)^
 m Sqrt[((2 ℓ0 + 1)^3)/(4 Pi)] ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ0, 0}, {ℓ0, 0}, 
   {ℓ0, 0}] ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ0, m1}, {ℓ0, M}, {ℓ0, -m}], 
 {m1, -ℓ0, ℓ0}, {M, -ℓ0, ℓ0}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}]
```

Comment: Are you sure about the factors of `Pi/2` inside the trigonometric functions of `dvec`? If those weren't there, the problem would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Yes , I want my dvec to be like that

Comment: I'd start by reversing the integration order: `Integrate[..., {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2π}]` because the `ϕ` integration is simple. But then, from what I can see in `a[0,0]`, it looks like the `θ` integration does not have a closed form. [Also, in my version "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" the integration you give does not work properly and returns a result that still depends on `θ`; may be a bug?]